# Rewrite Rules: CakePHP 1.2.1 with Nginx

Tags: cakephp, nginx

I made Cakephp 3 working with nginx, but still struggling for cakephp 1.2.1 to work with nginx, please help me.
By "not working" i mean blank page appears every time

- Config i've used for 1.2.1:

http://pastebin.com/RMMf1Xgb

- Config i've used for 3 and seems not work with 1.2.1:

http://pastebin.com/qJ9aJsLJ

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rules for CakePHP 1.2 can be found in the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Installation.html#pretty-urls-on-nginx

Just remember that 1.2 is no longer supported, and hasn't been supported for a very long time now! Also, CakePHP 1.2 probably doesn't work on PHP 5.3 or newer, which means that you'll need to run it on a different server than your CakePHP 3.x application.